# Refer to DES block in its java actions

Tags: anylogic

I remember reading once that there is a syntax to access a DES block while in its java actions similar to the `this` and `agent` syntaxes. I can't seem to find the syntax anywhere and would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use self

check the light bulb that you can find just besides the action, you can see more about it here:
https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling

this tells you what you can use in the action...

so if you are inside a wait block called waitx you can ask
self.size() which is equivalent to waitx.size()